# Is "performance" countable in the sentence below?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I wrote a sentence: "The model performance of other sites is similar to that as presented."

Question:

(1) Should I use "is"? I think "performance" is uncountable (refer in [This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133893/plural-and-countability-of-the-word-performance)), so I use "is". But there are "other sites", should it use "are" instead?

(2) In [this similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133893/plural-and-countability-of-the-word-performance), Mark Foskey says "...But you will definitely find that phrasing in the scientific literature...." in the end of his question. Does that mean both "performance" and "performances" are correct in the scientific literature?
 (*I should have asked him directly, but I don't have enough reputation to "add a comment" to him*)

(3) Is the expression "to that as presented" correct? What I want to say in a longer sentence is "The model performance of other sites is similar to the model performance of these sites that are presented in this paper." How can I simplify this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of the word "performance" or "performances" depends on whether you are referring to the sites as a group, in which it is assumed that their performance is similar to each other, or individually, with a different performance number for each.

In your paper, are you presenting performance for a lot of different sites separately, or a bunch of sites that can be grouped together by similar performance? If the sites in your paper are similar to each other or you are talking about only one site in this paper, then use

> The model performance of other sites is similar to what is presented here.

If the sites in your paper are quite different from each other and presented separately, and if there is a lot of variation in performance (especially if you report the various numbers representing their performance), then use

> The model performances of other sites are similar to those presented here.

The latter implies that you have somewhere a table of performances of other sites and their performances are different enough from each other to be presented separately.

The phrase "to that presented" is awkward and unnatural in this context.  Consider my examples instead.